# For $a,b,c \in R$ and $a,b,c>0$. Minimize $A=a^3+b^3+c^3$

Tags: maxima-minima

For $a,b,c \in R$ and $a,b,c>0$ satisfy $a^2+b^2+c^2=27$, minimize $$A=a^3+b^3+c^3$$

Comment: you should perhaps put it in a context. Like what are the prerequisites? Do you know e.g. about Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: @ H. H. Rugh: Ok. And yes i do

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By Power-Mean Inequality,

$\left(\dfrac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{3}\right)^{1/3}\ge \left(\dfrac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{3}\right)^{1/2}=3$

$a^3+b^3+c^3 \ge 81$

Comment: you can use other way ?

Comment: @WordShallow Why do you want to use another way? This is (very) elegant, simple and efficient.

Comment: Do you need an alternate approach ? The other approaches would be longer

Comment: Do you know Jensen's  Inequality ? Use it for $f(x)=x^{3/2}$

Comment: yes, i do -5 more to go...

Comment: Also with a,b,c=3 it becomes 81 so the bound is reached so 81 is the minima.